# Only listen to ONE Subdomain and ONE Port

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, subdomain, server

I need to find out how to listen to only one port-hostname combination and to return 404 on every other request.

My example:

I have set up a subdomain for owncloud that uses SSL and listens to port 12345 instead of 443. Let's assume this subdomain is oc.example.com. So I want nginx to **only listen to** https://oc.example.com:12345 but not to

- **http**://oc.example.com:12345
- https://oc.example.com:**X** where X != 12345
- https://**BLABLA**.example.com:12345
- **http://IP.IP.IP.IP**:12345
- **https**://IP.IP.IP.IP:12345
- and so on

If one requests any resource that does not exactly match https://oc.example.com:12345 an error (e.g. 404 not found) should be returned or the server simply should not respond.

My config so far looks like:

```
server {
    # I think there's something wrong here?
    listen 12345;
    server_name oc.example.com;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/owncloud/owncloud.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/owncloud/owncloud.key;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;

     # Path to the root of your installation
    root /var/some/path/to/my/owncloud/;

    client_max_body_size 10G; # set max upload size
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

    index index.php;
    error_page 403 = /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 = /core/templates/404.php;

    ... here are the definitions of my locations
}
```

I read the documentation and found that nginx first looks for the correct server definition by the port number. If there are multiple matches the server_name is used to find the correct definition. But I only have one definition!

Does somebody know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

nginx checks for the host header and chooses the appropriate virtual host.. in order to have it drop everything else, just add a 'catch-all' using the default_server directive:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server; 
  return 404;
}
```

all requests to oc.example.com:X, besides 12345, will be dropped by default since you didn't define other vhosts listening on other ports.